# Set values on List<List> from other list

Tags: c#, .net, performance, list

```
ClassA { List<ClassB> List1;}
ClassB { List<ClassC> List2;}
ClassC { int ID; }
ClassD { int ID; }
List<ClassD> List3;
```

I have method with the following signature:

```
SetValues (ref ClassA ObjectA, List<ClassD> List3)
```

I want to set **some of** the properties on the ClassC objects.
ClassB has a list of ClassC objects and i want to relate ClassC and ClassD by the id.

How can i do that without linq? (expecting that linq has a performance defect (I'm using .NET 3.5)

**LAST EDIT**

I was aiming for a non-linq solution thinking about performance, and i'm using 2 for eachs like alireza solution(dunno if i made the right call)

Any better solution? 
Ty

Comment: Do you have some sample code of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You don't need `ref` to modify contents of a list.

Comment: "*expecting that LINQ has a performance defect*" - it might have a *slight* overhead but how can you rule it out without actually benchmarking it? Also, there is no where near enough information to actually answer this question correctly - how does `ClassB` link to `ClassC`? You need someway of looking up the other list.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. I did leave a reason, not that I *have* to but I generally don't down vote for no good reason. Once the question becomes answerable I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @nowhe - no, such comments are not required and not even recommmended.

Comment: HenkHolterman and @James: Sorry for the ignorance. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *BartoszKP*  said `ref` is not needed. Just iterate through collections and nested collections:

```
SetValues (List<ClassB> List1, List<ClassC> List3)
{
    foreach(classB b in list1)
    {
       foreach(classC c in b.List2)
       {
          c.Property1 = someValue;// set a property here
          .... 
          ....
          .... and similar things here
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the update this is pretty much the correct approach but as it stands it's not the answer. You need to pull the item from `List3` which is going to be used to update `b.List2`. Also, I would do it the opposite way, I would iterate `List3` in the second loop and pull the item from `b.List2` because chances are you won't be updating *every* item in `b.List2`.

Answer (score 1):

First, You don't need `ref` to modify contents of a list since it's a reference type.

Second, how do you want to find the related `ClassB` objects? Here i presume that you have an identifier called `ID` and another property `SomeProperty` that you want to modify:

```
public class ClassC
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use `Enumerable.Join` to link both and an anonymous type to store the related informations.

```
public static void SetValues(List<ClassB> listOfB, List<ClassC> listOfC)
{
    var bAndC = from b in listOfB
                from bc in b.List2
                join c in listOfC
                on bc.ID equals c.ID
                select new{ bc, c };
    foreach(var both in bAndC)
    {
        both.bc.SomeProperty = both.c.SomeProperty;
    }
}
```